# Spring Boot Batch application, the Actuator endpoint triggers Tomcat application auto restarts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, openapi, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

I have a Spring batch application which auto restarts every 6hrs and I enabled the debugging on the `logback.xml` file. I clearly shows after `Security checking request GET /xxx/actuator/health` it calls socket closed on `org.apache.tomcat` which results in shutting down the application. Again after few seconds, the application is restarted by itself.

This is my `application.yml` file

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  application:
    description: Project used to import Transunion data from a CSV file we receive on a monthly basis with data on vehicles.
    name: tu-models-data-importer
  main:
    banner-mode: 'off'
    logStartupInfo: false
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  batch:
    initialize-schema: always
    job:
      enabled: false
springdoc:
  show-actuator: false
  swagger-ui:
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
    displayRequestDuration: true
    operations-sorter: method
    tryItOutEnabled: true
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: false
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: always
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health, loggers, metrics, info
        exclude: threaddump
```

I tried commenting out the following properties and test but it has not worked:

```yaml
main:
    banner-mode: 'off'
    logStartupInfo: false
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  batch:
    initialize-schema: always
    job:
      enabled: false
```

Comment: Not related to Spring Batch per se, Spring Batch does not alter Spring Boot's actuator. The `spring-batch` tag of the question should be removed.